# jQuery drop down to fill second drop down and text field

Tags: jquery

I want to use jQuery to populate a second select box, and a text field. I have the second select box getting populated correctly when a selection is made in the first. I have not been able to get it to populate the text field though.

The data is retrieved from a MySQL database. Below is the code that I have working for the first select box to make a selection in the second.

My jQuery code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#shipment").change(function() {
    $("#vender").load("selection.php", $("#shipment"));
  }).trigger("change");
});
</script>
```

Form Fields relevant to this:

```
<html>
<label for="shipments">Shipment: </label><select id="shipment" name="shipment_id">
<?php if(isset($shipment_selection)) { echo $shipment_selection; } ?> //echos options from db.
</select>
<label for="vender">Vender: </label><select id="vender" name="vender_id"></select>
<label for="cost">Cost: </label>><input type="text" id="cost" name="cost" value="" />
</html>
```

PHP Script that gets the data:

```
<?php
include('../scripts/db_config.php');

if(isset($_POST['shipment_id'])) {
    if($_POST['shipment_id'] == 1) {
    $sql = 'SELECT id AS vender_id, name AS vender_name FROM venders'; //shows all venders, when shipment is none.
    }
else {
$sql = 'SELECT venders.id AS vender_id, venders.name AS vender_name, shipment.qty AS qty, shipment.cost AS cost FROM shipments INNER JOIN venders ON venders.id=shipments.vender_id WHERE shipments.id='.$_POST['shipment_id']; //Select vender associated with specific shipment.
}
$stmt = $db->query($sql);
$data = array();
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $data[] = $row;
    //echo '<option value="'.$row['vender_id'].'">'.$row['vender_name'].'</option>'; //populates second select box.
    }
echo json_encode($data);
}
```

I will secure the PHP code better after I get this working.

Any suggestions on how to get a selection in the first select box to populate the second select box, and the text field would be great.

Apologies if the formatting is off; I am blind, so I am not sure how it actually looks on screen.

Answer (score 0):

The file accessed by `.load()` should return the HTML to be dumped into the given element. You have it returning JSON, for some unknown reason. Remove that, and uncomment the line outputting options.

Alternatively, instead of using `.load()`, use a full AJAX call and iterate through the returned JSON to insert the options that way.